# Error: Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag' when trying to output renderValueBox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

New to R and R Shiny. My goal is to output the maximum value of a column by a valueBoxOutput, whilst the value is able to update when filters are changed by the user e.g Date etc. I am receiving Error: Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag' which I have no clue what it means and I cannot see why the code is wrong.

ui.R

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
 dashboardHeader(title = "Metric Tracker")
dashboardSidebar(
          sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard", icon = icon("city")),

dashboardBody(fluidRow(
      tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Dashboard",
        box(collapsible = TRUE, title = "All Brands",status =  "info",solidHeader = TRUE, width = 8, plotlyOutput("valuePlot", height = "500px"), plotlyOutput("testplot", height = "500px")),
        box(width = 4,title = "Inputs", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning", selectInput("value", "1st Value to Track:" , choices =  c("Units_Ordered", "Buy_Box_Percentage", "Ordered_Product_Sales", "Session_Percentage","aov"), selected = "Ordered_Product_Sales", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),
          selectInput("value2", "2nd Value to Track:" , choices =  c("Units_Ordered", "Buy_Box_Percentage", "Ordered_Product_Sales", "Session_Percentage","aov"), selected = "Units_Ordered", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE),
          selectInput("marketplace", "Select Marketplace", choices = c("UK","DE","FR","IT","ES")),
          sliderInput("date", "Date Range:", min = as.Date("2019-07-06","%Y-%m-%d"), max = as.Date("2019-10-26","%Y-%m-%d"), value = c(as.Date( "2019-07-06"),as.Date( "2019-10-26")),step = 7, timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d")),

   valueBoxOutput("max", width =3), valueBoxOutput("min", width = 3)      
        ),
```

server ( I am only including relevant parts of my code so if you believe it maybe somewhere else that is distrputive let me know, but to know everything else works perfectly)

```
server <- function(input, output){

output$max <- renderValueBox({
maxsales <- filter(metricx2, Date >= input$date[1] & Date <= input$date[2] & Marketplace %in% input$marketplace)
   maxsales1 <- max(maxsales$Ordered_Product_Sales)%>%
  valueBox(value =maxsales1,subtitle = "Maximum Sales Value")

})

output$min <- renderValueBox({
  valueBox(
    value = min(metricx2$Ordered_Product_Sales), 
    subtitle = "Minimum Sales Value"
  )
})
}  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

metricx2 is the data frame that I want to pull from. The 'Min' part works but its not reactive to the inputs of the user. Moreover, R has sometimes prompted my to input a reactive function within the render. Yet this has not worked for me. As well as, R struggled to find Ordered_Product_Sales even though it is clearly there which is frustrating.

Hope someone can help and point out an obvious mistake I am probably making.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find the problem? One reason you did not get many responses is your reprex is not short enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want the pipe at the end of this line:

```
maxsales1 <- max(maxsales$Ordered_Product_Sales)%>%
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is possibly on this server line:

`maxsales1 <- max(maxsales$Ordered_Product_Sales)%>% valueBox(value =maxsales1,subtitle = "Maximum Sales Value")`

Remove the pipe `%>%` and it should work.

})